What makes alternative winning conditions good or bad in chess variants?
For chess variants that keep all or most of chess movement rules but with different winning conditions (can be in addition to the normal winning condition or replacing it), what properties/characteristics are generally considered to make a winning condition good or bad, or makes the variant better or worse as a game in terms of strategic depth, fun, etc? Are there general types of winning conditions that are considered to be good or bad, or widely liked or disliked by players? Can include alternative winning conditions in puzzles with different goals, if they make the puzzles good/bad, even if they are not played from the start of a game.
